# Autolayout issue with multiline views in two stack views

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-autolayout

[image]

I have one stack view in which I have added

1. 1 Image
2. 1 Stack view

In inner `stackView` I have added 4 more `stackViews`. 3 inner `stackView` is having two label

1. Normal label
2. Multiline label.

How should I add `autoLayout` constraint so that it can work on every device.

I am trying to add `>=` constraint for height but its not working.
Please guide.

Comment: Can you please post the screen shot of your UI design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem using content hugging priority. :-)